# Can't teardown django test database if async queries are used

Tags: python, django, postgresql, asynchronous

I have a django project with postgres database configured.
Here is the relevant part of requirements.txt:

```
Django==5.0.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
```

Here I have one model defined:

```py
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And a test case:

```py
class ItemTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_create(self):
        asyncio.run(Item.objects.acreate(name="Test"))
        self.assertEqual(Item.objects.count(), 1)
```

Issue:

When I'm running the tests using `python manage.py test` - tests are passed but at the end i see an exception that test runner can't destroy test database.

```
2024-01-18 19:05:03 django.db.utils.OperationalError: database "test_axpress" is being accessed by other users
2024-01-18 19:05:03 DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

Is there a way to ensure that all connections are closed before tearing down the database?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to drop all connections to postgresql using raw SQL.

```
# project/testrunner.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import connection
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

default_database = settings.DATABASES["default"]["NAME"]
test_database = f"test_{default_database}"

query = f"""
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '{test_database}'
AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
"""


class CustomTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    def teardown_databases(self, old_config, **kwargs):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
        return super().teardown_databases(old_config, **kwargs)
```

```
settings.py

...

TEST_RUNNER = "project.testrunner.CustomTestRunner"
```